# Timer loop throws exception

Tags: autoit

[image: Error screenshot]

My script to automate the game Vikings is doing the first step in the loop (dragging) but throws the error above on click event (which stops the script):

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
Func Terminate() ;This function forces the script to stop when you hit the escape key in the top left corner of your keyboard
    MsgBox(0, 'Ending', 'Macro Ended')
    Exit
EndFunc

;Activate your game window
WinActivate("Vikings")
Sleep(200)

;Looping thru 120 minutes
$Minutes = 120
Local $60Count = 0, $begin = TimerInit(), $popup = 1
While $Minutes > $60Count

    $dif = TimerDiff($begin)
    $dif2 = StringLeft($dif, StringInStr($dif, ".") - 1)
    $Count = Int($dif / 1000)
    $60Count = Int($Count / 60)

    ;Selecting Max RRS Food
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    MouseClickDrag("left", 784, 297, 992, 298, 500)
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    ;send
    MouseClick("left", [1156, 793, [1, [3]]])

    ;Selecting Max RRS Lumber
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    MouseClickDrag("left", 784, 381, 989, 381)
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    ;send
    MouseClick("left", [1156, 793, [1, [3]]])

    ;Selecting Max RRS Iron
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    MouseClickDrag("left", 781, 467, 988, 464, 500)
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    ;send
    MouseClick("left", [1156, 793, [1, [3]]])

    ;Selecting Max RRS Stone
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    MouseClickDrag("left", 781, 548, 988, 548, 500)
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    ;send
    MouseClick("left", [1156, 793, [1, [3]]])

    ;Selecting Max RRS Silver
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    MouseClickDrag("left", 781, 631, 988, 633, 500)
    Sleep(Random(800, 1200, 1))
    ;send
    MouseClick("left", [1156, 793, [1, [3]]])
WEnd

MsgBox(64, "Time-Up!!", "Your " & $Minutes & " minutes have passed    ")
```

I changed the code:

```
$iBegin = TimerInit()

While TimerDiff($iBegin) < whatever_delay_you_want
    Your_Code
WEnd
```

But it did not work.

Comment: EXPRESSION ERROR sorry for typo.

Comment: It didn't give you syntax errors with the `MouseClick` commands? Strange...

Comment: @AlexanderEismond There is no error on line 14 (posted code did not throw that error, post the actual code which that error comes from please).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood the documentation for [MouseClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm).
Where it says `MouseClick ( "button" [, x, y [, clicks = 1 [, speed = 10]]] )` the square brackets `[]` indicate optional parameters.
See [function notes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/function_notes.htm) under the "Optional parameters" section. Basically you should not include the square brackets in your code.

Also, I would recommend test running your code in the editor that comes with autoit (SciTE Script Editor) since it will tell you exactly where the error in your code is.
[image]

[image]

I am really surprised that this compiled into an exe...